# Do Javascript event handlers block?

Tags: javascript, events, synchronization, backbone.js

(Specifically, I'm using Backbone Model events)

Can someone help me understand how javascript events work?  The following is not working the way I expected and it's left me confused:

In backbone, I make a change to my model, and immediately afterwards I run some code:

```
var myVar;
myModel.set('someAttr', true);  // Change my model
myVar = executeSomeFunc();  // Now run some code
```

Then somewhere else in my codebase I listen for the event and handle it (in my case I am wrapping this model with a collection):

```
myCollection.on('change:someAttr', changeHandler);  // Listen for the event
```

What I'm finding is that `myVar = executeSomeFunc()` is not executing until all the event handlers on the `change:someAttr` event are done firing. (I've checked by attaching a time consuming event handler onto the event)

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. JavaScript is not multithreaded. When you trigger events, all event handlers are immediately executed.

Comment: My understanding was that the event handler runs synchronously with the "trigger", but that you get normal semantics within the event handler function - i.e - it could yield to another waiting event-handler at function-call boundaries - say, function calls inside your event handler. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Wow...don't know why but this just totally through me for a curve...I've always assumed this stuff was all non-blocking!  Thanks for the lesson in js 101

Comment: jQuery, at least, specifies that handlers are executed in the order they are bound. That would imply to me that there is no yielding. It is my understanding that basic javascript works this way as well - binding events is essentially just a queue of methods that are executed one after another. There really isn't a concept of yielding.

Comment: I was wrong! (The only way to yield is setTimeout). As for synchronicity of event handlers, this explains it really thoroughly (it would seem the answer is "it depends"): http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth

Answer (score 1):

Everything in javascript blocks, it just depends when. If you set a handler the other functions, fire the event for the handler and run other functions it will get executed in the exact order i have enumerated them. The point of event-handlers is to execute code when triggering something, but it will never be asynchronous. So the answer for you is that YES this is the expected behavior. For understanding the heaven and the hell of javascript just search for Crockford's speeches about javascript.

Hope this helps.